# Azure Client IServiceFilter doesn't work

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to implement an Azure Mobile service in my android application, using the official xamarin's azure component. I've to invoke the asure service using a filter, and I've simply done this:

```
class Filter : IServiceFilter 
{ 
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Handle(IServiceFilterRequest request, IServiceFilterContinuation continuation) 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    } 
}
```

As you can see it's a simple implementation of IServiceFilter, but it fails! Here's the error

> TimestampFilter' does not implement interface member
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilter.Handle(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterRequest,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterContinuation)'.
>   'TimestampFilter.Handle(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterRequest,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterContinuation)'
>   cannot implement
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilter.Handle(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterRequest,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IServiceFilterContinuation)'
>   because it does not have the matching return type of
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Anyone knows why?? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that the return type is incorrect, so I had a look at the Assembly Browser:

```
public Task<IServiceFilterResponse> Handle(IServiceFilterRequest request,IServiceFilterContinuation continuation) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

That should compile for you now